# android - how to change style.xml at run time?

Tags: android, styles

I have a layout that has number of  textviews . these text views have one style and I want to change this style at run time for example change the text size of all text views. how can I do this??

Answer (score 1):

Make an ArrayList, add the TextViews to the ArrayList in onCreate, then when you want to change the style call a method like this:

```
private void changeTextViewAppearance() { 
    for (TextView tv : tvArrayList)
        tv.setTextAppearance(R.id.my_res_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setTextAppearance` function !

Comment: I have to chenge style.xml becuase I want all of the textviews change at the same time

Comment: yes, with this function you can change current style to other one style.xml  Or  you can simply write a function like this : setTextColor  setTextSize setBackgroud ...

Comment: can u show me an example please??